# Why does \w match Non-English characters in Mac OS X PHP environment?

Tags: php, regex

I found that "\w" can match Chinese characters in my Mac OS X PHP environment. but same code does not working on Linux.

```
php -r "echo preg_match('/^\w+$/','人1234', \$m).chr(10); var_dump(\$m);"
```

Mac OS X 11.11.3 with PHP 5.6.18 (cli), PHP 5.4.45 (cli) result

```
1
array(1) {
  [0] =>
  string(7) "人1234"
}
```

Cent OS 6 with PHP 5.6.18 (cli), PHP 5.2.17p1 (cli) result

```
0
array(0) {
}
```

PHP manual says

> The definition of letters and digits is controlled by PCRE's character tables, and may vary if locale-specific matching is taking place. For example, in the "fr" (French) locale, some character codes greater than 128 are used for accented letters, and these are matched by \w."

I guess something link to the PCRE library. Could anybody explain why?

Comment: It is clear there is some setting that makes all regexps Unicode-aware.

Comment: use `locale` command to see encoding

Comment: @anonymous locale is same, en_US.UTF-8

Comment: Try with `u` modifier (i.e. Unicode UTF-16) like as `/^\w+$/u` instead of `/^\w+$/`

Comment: It is not clear what setting is in charge, but you can always use the hint from the [Android pattern page](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) (in Android regex, `\w` is always Unicode aware), use `^[a-zA-Z0-9_]+$` instead.

Comment: Thanks for the tips, i know how to deal with Unicode chars. i just wanna know why "\w" matchs are different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is all about how PCRE is compiled alongside PHP:

```
pcre *pcre_compile(const char *pattern,
      int options,
      const char **errptr,
      int *erroffset,
      const unsigned char *tableptr);
```

In this function, that is responsible for compiling RegExes into their internal forms,  `options` argument is a list of bits including `PCRE_UCP`  (UCP = Unicode Character Properties) which allows `\w`, `\d` and other tokens use unicode properties and it seems that PHP's PCRE on your Mac OS X machine is compiled with this flag on.

There is also an special modifier `(*UCP)` which you can use on the fly that even if your PCRE is not compiled with `PCRE_UCP` flag set, you can have such an option enabled on runtime.

E.g. `/(*UCP)\w+/` matches unicode characters as well. ([See it online](https://regex101.com/r/aH1dP7/1))

From [PCRE website](http://www.pcre.org/pcre.txt):

> PCRE handles caseless matching, and determines whether  characters 
>   are letters,  digits, or whatever, by reference to a set of tables,
>   indexed by character code point.
>
> When running in `UTF-8` mode, or in the  16- or 32-bit libraries, this
>   applies only to characters with code points less than 256. By default,
>   higher-valued code  points  never  match  escapes such  as `\w` or
>   `\d`.
>
> However, if PCRE is built with Unicode property support, all
>   characters can be tested with \p and \P,  or,  alternatively, the 
>   PCRE_UCP option can be set when a pattern is compiled; **this causes
>   `\w` and friends to use Unicode property support instead of the 
>   built-in tables**.
>
> The  use  of  locales  with Unicode is discouraged. If you are
>   handling characters with code points greater than 128,  you  should 
>   either  use Unicode support, or use locales, but not try to mix the
>   two.